# jqgrid: Sorting not working after dynamically adding records

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which initially gets populated with some records. User has the option to add more rows to the grid. But, after adding new rows, if user tries to sort the records, the result is inconsistent and some of the records are lost in the grid.

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/68/

HTML:

```
<table id="sg1"></table>
<div id="psg1"></div>
</br>
<button id="new" type="button">Add New</button>
```

Code:

```
jQuery("#sg1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoencode: true,
    height: 'auto',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollrows: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'Id',index:'Id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    caption: "Test Grid"
});

var initialData = [
        {Id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test 12349",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {Id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
        ];

var subData = [
        {Id:"3",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test 12349",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {Id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
        ];

jQuery("#sg1")[0].addJSONData(initialData);

var i=2;

$('#new').on('click', function(){
    i = i+i;
    jQuery("#sg1").jqGrid(
        'addRowData',
        $.jgrid.randId(),
        {Id:i,invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test"+i,note:"note" + i,amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"});    
});
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

a. Launch the fiddler (you will see a test grid with 2 records)
b. Now, click on the 'Add New' button and then try sorting by clicking on any column header.

**Question:**

Is there anything wrong with the code? Why some of the records are disappearing?

**Environment:**
jqgrid 4.6.0, jquery 1.11.1 and IE 9

Comment: The reason of the problem: wrong filling of **initial** data. You should **not use** `addJSONData`. Instead of that you can use `data` parameter of jqGrid: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/99x50s2s/70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `addRow` [method](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Ainline_editing#addrow) to append data. Here is an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/69/

```
$('#new').on('click', function(){
       i = i+i;
   var parameters =
{
    initdata :  {Id:i,invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test"+i,note:"note" + i,amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
    position :"last"
};
    jQuery("#sg1").jqGrid('addRow',parameters); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing 'addRow' function to me. I am doing further investigation on how this function fit's into my actual code in project.

Comment: Looks like addRowData deletes the existing rows but addRow appends!

Comment: As per documentation, it looks like addRow is a wrapper on top of addRowData method. addRow method calls addRowData.

Comment: One can use `addRowData` instead of `addRow`. It's important just that the original usage of `addJSONData` was wrong.